# What monospace fonts are available in Python and Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, fonts, monospace

I have seen the term 'monospace' at dozen of places. Can you tell me what does monospace font mean and what monospace fonts are available in Python and Tkinter?

Comment: A monospace font is a font where all characters have the same width `(like this)`. What fonts are available depends on what font you have installed.

Comment: my best guess, without any research is that. monospace as the name suggests, has one default spacing for each character?like in some fonts when you type HELLO and then change the font, the size might vary , even tho all you change is font. To avoid this, we have monospace which gives equal spaced characters, no matter where you put them on.

Comment: Tkinter has access to whatever monospace fonts you have installed on your OS. It doesn't have its own set of fonts.

Comment: How can I check which fonts are installed on my OS? Because I have never installed any font by myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"Monospace"* just means that all characters take the same, fixed width for each character.

The converse is a *"proportional"* font where narrower letters e.g `i` take less space and wider letters e.g. `m` take more space.

Which ones are available depend on what you have installed.